# Error while reading data, error message: Could not parse '1/31/2017' as date for field starting at location

Tags: csv, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to create a table using a ~17MB csv. I have table schema in a json file and csv file(table data) also copied from GCP Bucket to my local. This is required as using GCP console we cannot directly use file from GCP Bucket.

But I am getting a error , screenshot below. 
I was able to up **successfully create table with small 200 rows** sample of same data set.

BIGquery supports YYYY-MM-DD format and my input data set has date in format '1/31/2017'. I did not change date format in small data set I uploaded but GCP automatically converted it to YYYY-MM-DD format.

**I did following:**

```
  1) So did not change format in main ~17MB CSV file and I got errors.
  2) I changed format in Input CSV format but still got error, as they were not changing correctly in file I uploaded in Bucket.
```

I am not sure how to resolve the issue, please help, may be I am going in wrong direction.

[image]

Schema in json format for column shown in error message

```
{
  "mode": "NULLABLE",
  "name": "Docs",
  "type": "INTEGER"
},
{
  "mode": "NULLABLE",
  "name": "end_date",
  "type": "DATE"
},
```

Sample data where **NO** I got no error:

[image]

Data where I **got error**( pasted data from row number 1100 as per error message)
[image]

Comment: For me, I'd like to see a few sample rows that work and some that fail (as an attachment) and also I'd like to see (in detail) the schema for the table.

Comment: This kind of things usually work for us using ISO dates y-m-d or unixtimestampts.

Comment: @Koban I will upload the field error field in question schema and records for which it worked and it did not work..will that work as this is very big record

Comment: @Kolban added details , I could not attach data  , I did not find a way.

Comment: If you move the row in the CSV that is causing the problem to near the front, does the problem still occur?  Am curious if the error is based on the content of the row in text or based on the fact that it is 1100th row in the file.

Comment: @Kolban as suggested I did it but got a strange result, still same error 'Failure details:
- Error while reading data, error message: Could not parse
'1/31/2017' as date for field end_date (position 1)
starting at location 1100' but on location 1100 I see '12/15/2016
' in new dataset.

Comment: Can you pastebin (or otherwise post) a small sample of the data in a CSV text file and I for one will attempt to load it into a BQ dataset at my end?

Comment: @Tokci Did you figure out a solution to this? I'm in the same boat =)

Comment: @no Tag Kolban and share a sample dataset with him and he may be able to help

Comment: @Tokci are you still facing this problem?